# logging mysql queries wont work

Tags: mysql

I am running on Ubuntu and I've modified /etc/mysql/my.cnf with the following:
[pastie of my.cnf](http://pastie.org/5516923#69-70) and i've chown it to mysql:mysql and chmoded it to 777. No matter what I try when I run a few queries nothing gets logged. What am I doing wrong? I have also tried commenting out general_log_file and general_log and use log = and its its the same thing.

update: i did restart mysql after changes.
update: here is the mysql variables: http://pastie.org/5517087

Comment: are you sure that you have written the right path?

Comment: yes, and I just double checked it.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to check the following:

1) Make sure that you restarted the service and that no errors appear during the restart, either on the command prompt, or in the mysql error log file

2) In your my.cnf you are using:

```
general_log_file = /var/www/logs/mysql-query.log
```

make sure that the user mysqld (or whatever your mysql service is running as), has the proper permissions to write this folder. The /var/www/ folder is usually intended for apache usage, not mysql usage, so I would suggest /var/log/ or /var/log/mysqld

3) Make sure that the my.cnf you are editing, is the one your mysqld is really running. In many cases when you are using some other software (like cpanel, plesk, etc), the default folders are not used and the configs being used are somewhere else. You can search around your system for other my.cnf using:

```
locate my.cnf
```

Comment: maybe if you can tell me a few commands to type to show settings to you.

Comment: That should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: @juergend I understand your point on why this could be a comment because I stated my answer as a question, however I have seen LOTS of cases where the problem was just the fact that the person making the changes to the config forgot to restart the services. So in too many cases just having someone remind you of this, is the solution.

Comment: Since that did not bring the solution it is still not an answer to the question.

Comment: @juergend that doesn't validate your point because the original question didn't state that he restarted the service, so it could have been a valid solution to the problem as it was explained. But oh well, it doesn't really matter, I will edit my answer with some additional info since you are right that it wasn't very well explained.